# Bootstrap 3 : Increase size of badge

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

As per bootstrap 4, if you use heading tag to surround the spans, the badge adjust the size as per the heading as mentioned in documentation.

```
<h1>Example heading <span class="badge badge-secondary">New</span></h1>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/badge/

[image]

However, I have bootstrap 3 and it seems it doesn't support this behaviour.
Is there any way in bootstrap 3 to increase size of badge ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for dirty custom CSS. Look at `.label`. The BS3 equivalent to the BS4

```
<h1>Example heading <span class="badge badge-secondary">New</span></h1>
```

and so on is

```
<h1>Example heading <span class="label label-default">New</span></h1>
<h2>Example heading <span class="label label-default">New</span></h2>
<h3>Example heading <span class="label label-default">New</span></h3>
<h4>Example heading <span class="label label-default">New</span></h4>
<h5>Example heading <span class="label label-default">New</span></h5>
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/5sL7ny2w/**

Answer (score 1):

```css
.badge-parent>span{
  font-size:3rem;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="badge-parent">
  <span class="badge badge-primary">Span</span>
</h1>
```

Comment: Worked in first go. Thanks